# Multiple entry-points in GWT Application: How does bootstrapping, History-Token and Place-Management work?

Tags: gwt

I have now splitted up my application into two major modules:

1. Admin area
   Anything that is related to the administration area for some certain users.
2. Landing page area
   The landing page for public users.

The reason why I have done this is because maybe one day it will be just easier to develop in two separate projects where each of them should be able to run as a standalone. Therefore both modules do have their own `EntryPoint`.

The things I am not sure about is how to handle e.g. the history and places of both of them. I am definitely going to have at least two `ActivityManager` to handle the different places of both modules but how can I e.g. separate the `PlaceHistoryMapper` into both modules?

Another thing I am not sure about is how I could bootstrap this application as such that each module is still able to run without the other.

And talking about bootstrapping: Can somebody tell my in which order `onModuleLoad()` is getting called? How can I make sure e.h. that running "main" `EntryPoint` gets executed first in order to initialize everything correctly before the others are getting called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: don't do that (that just won't work, at least not without a considerable amount of error-prone work).

If you want to make it easier to split the project in two in the future, just make it modular. That's exactly what Activities are about.

Your `PlaceHistoryMapper` and `ActivityMapper`s are specific to one application, they're about how you tie everything together.
You can modularize them by making them delegate to other `PlaceHistoryMapper`s and `ActivityMapper`s.

Comment: Hi again :D ! I changed a lot and modularized everything in an `admin` module and a `landing` module (didn't find a better name for that). What I have done now is having a `BaseActivityMapper`, a `AdminActivityMapper` and a `LandingActivityMapper`. The `BaseActivityMapper` just delegates the `getActivity()` call to `Admin*` or `Landing*` according to the base class of the place `AbstractAdminPlace` or `AbstractLandingPlace`. I am not sure if that isn't a little overkill but it works and imho it's quite comprehensible. I am not able to have "standalones" here but maybe that isn't necessary.

Comment: Btw. the `BaseActivityMapper` is in its  own `core` module where I now have the core functionality that is needed by the `admin` and the `landing` module. Is what I am doing "*sane*" in the sense of a GWT project?

Comment: IIUC, sounds good (I'd have put the `BaseActivityMapper` in a `bigapp` module so you have a diamond-shaped dependency graph: `bigapp` depends on `admin` and `landing` –as it ties them together in one big app–, and each of `admin` and `landing` depends on `core` for the shared functionalities; but maybe I misunderstood what you did…).

Comment: You're right that would be more comprehensible - it shouldn't be a problem to make that dependency graph. I "almost" got it that way except that my `module.gwt.xml` at the moment includes all modules directly but I guess I'll change that :) Thanks on this side too! :)